# Any way to recursively update a tree in SQL?

Tags: sql, recursion, tree, sql-update

I've got a database table that represents a bunch of trees.  The first three columns are GUIDs that look like this:

```
NODE_ID (PK)
PARENT_NODE_ID (FK to same table, references NODE_ID)
TREE_ID (FK to another table)
```

It's possible to move a node to a different tree.  The tricky part is bringing all its child-nodes with it.  That takes a recursive update.  (And yes, I realize this is kinda bad design in the first place.  I didn't design it.  I just have to maintain it, and I can't change the database schema.)

It would be nice if I could do the update in SQL, as a stored procedure.  But I can't think of how to implement the recursive operation required in set logic, without employing a cursor.  Does anyone know of a reasonably simple way to pull this off?

Comment: Note: the tree_id is redundant, and that causes the update problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Postgres or MS SQL 2005 you can use a recursive update, otherwise, you may want to consider using a method other than an adjacency list.  I saw a presentation a few weeks ago speaking about these issues and storing hierarchical data.  Here is a link:

http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-object-oriented-models-in-sql

Start @ slide 40

Comment: I am using MS SQL 2005.  How do you "use a recursive update"?  I'm not what anyone would mistake for a SQL guru...